# Filling certain directories

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making this program to "fill" a certain directory. But the issue is when I tick "auto hide" it reappears after about 30-40 seconds.

Is there any other way around this as it would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Drive_Filler
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = "H:/";
    }


    public bool isRunning = true;
    public string current;
    string[] alpha = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        createnew(textBox1.Text);
    }

    public void createnew(string dir)
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            current = alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)];
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + current);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where / on what element do you tick auto-hide?

Comment: what reappears? What/where is this `auto hide`?  This is not enough information to go with.

Comment: What are you "Auto hide"ing?

Comment: You're running an endless loop on your UI thread in `createnew`. Don't do that. use a backgroundworker or a Task. Once that is fixed, we can talk about hiding and re-appearing.

Answer (score 1):

The form reappeared because it was being unresponsive. Also, there are many problems in your code, and I couldn't understand of your purposes either.

First of all, *createnew* has an infinite loop. It will run in the UI Thread, causing your form to appear as a sign to warn user about unresponsive state. Moreover, *rnd* should be declared once only. Random of C# (and many other languages) use a time-dependent default seed value. In other words, with 2 Random instances initialized almost simultaneously, both Random's arrays of values will be the same.

So I suggest creating *Random rnd* as a field of your *Form1*, and put the loop in another thread, using Task, BackgroundWorker, ThreadPool or anything.

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (isRunning)
            {
                current = alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)] + alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)];
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + current);
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: As an additional improvement suggestion, I would replace the repeated calls to `alpha[rnd.Next(0, 26)]` for setting `current` with using [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and a loop. In fact, I'd further argue that the `alpha` array declaration from the original code is entirely unnecessary if one knows how to convert between integers and characters in the desired range.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Yup! There are so much things to be fixed overall. I think none of us, including me, can give him a perfect answer.